# NSPredicate with Swift and Core Data

Tags: swift

i have a Core Data Object and i have 2 Fieds (one String(GUID) and one Int which i want to use as Filter)

So in SQL it would be "SELECT * FROM Answers WHERE qIndex = 1 AND GUID = '88bfd206-82fb-4dd0-b65d-096f8902855c'

Ive tried it with Core Data but i am not able to Filter with the String Value.

Here is my Code

```
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Answers")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

    let resultPredicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "qIndex = %i", qIndex)
    let resultPredicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "formUUID = %s", formUUID)

    var compound = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates([resultPredicate1, resultPredicate2])
    request.predicate = compound


    var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
```

Any ideas what i am doing Wrong? With the Same Code and Filter for 2 Integer Values it works fine.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You used the String Format Specifier %i. I think it should be %d for a decimal or a %@ for a NSNumber. Not %i for int, which doesn't exist

Comment: @Xean: Both "%d" and "%i" can be used to format an int, they are identical.

Comment: why is results not empty when there isn't anything matching? I get [<ChartModel: 0x1740b6c20> (entity: Charts; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://F542870C-1070-40D2-BC59-8FCE71D18224/Charts/p1> ; data: <fault>)]

Comment: And results.count > 0 ?

Comment: your better of actually faulting your data since it will reduce the memory profile of your object graph. It also lets you only load what you need. If you are pre-fetching other fields with a fetchRequest those values will be populated and not faulted.

Comment: BTW since swift supports string interpolation you doesn't have to use old-fashioned format-vargargs style anymore and could replace `NSPredicate(format: "qIndex = %i", qIndex)` with `NSPredicate(format: "qIndex = \(qIndex)")`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If `formUUID` is an `NSString` or a Swift `String` then you have to use the
`%@` placeholder:

```
let resultPredicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "formUUID = %@", formUUID)
```

Comment: Note to the edit suggestion: Both `=` and `==` can be used in a predicate string.

Answer (score 8):

This is not the exact response to your question, but a problem people might now encouter with your code now:

In the latest version of XCode, you must now unwrap the predicate, like this:

```
var compound = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates([predicate1!, predicate2!])
```

because NSPredicate initializer now return NSPredicate? type.

Comment: As you say yourself, this is not really an answer but rather a note. For this reason you should add this as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I've been registered on stackOverflow only for a few weeks, and my reputation (1) doesn't allow me to comment other people's questions/answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of worrying about `%@` conversions and then composing `AND` predicates, you can use the [PredicatePal](https://github.com/pixelglow/PredicatePal) framework:

```
let compound = *(Key("qIndex") == qIndex && Key("formUUID") == formUUID)
```

Assuming that `qIndex` and `formUUID` are the correct type, Swift will automatically deduce the correct types for the `Key` objects.