# NSPredicate with strings does not appear to return results

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift, nspredicate

```
func getFetchRequest(#entityName: String, address value: String) -> NSFetchRequest {
    var fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "address = %s", value)
    println(fetch)
    return fetch
}
```

The problem is that it was working with Xcode <6.1 and stopped working with 6.1.

Passing `getFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity", address: "test")` gives the following

```
(
    entity: Entity;
    predicate: (address == "s");
    sortDescriptors: ((null));
    type: NSManagedObjectResultType;
)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `println(predicate)` to the various working and non-working cases?

Comment: Writing tests now to confirm, but it gives "nil" for the values instead of "(...)". This is incorrect, given that stepping through, there are values within the variable passed to NSPredicate. Edit: Will edit once the tests are completed.

Comment: @MartinR It is strange. If I do straight unit tests, it works. The code is not structured like I have in the question and I will need to update to reflect the actual problem in development. Stepping through the code, has the value, but doing println(predicate) has "nil" for the value. I don't understand that at all.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution found in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855159/nspredicate-with-swift-and-core-data) Might count this duplicate.

**Solution**

```
NSPredicate(format: "address = %s", value)
```

Should be:

```
NSPredicate(format: "address = %@", value)
```